# Is it possible to use External package while developing appExchange app

Tags: lightning-web-components, appexchange

I am new to salesforce ecosystem and I am trying to make my first appExchange app but I am wondering if it is possible to use an external package like lwc-router while developing an application for appExchange?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Just make sure that code that you use is licensed for you to use for commercial purposes. In this case, [lwcRouter uses the MIT License](https://github.com/chandrakiran-dev/lwc-router/blob/master/LICENSE.md), which means you can use it in your projects if you want to.